# Java JDBC: Cannot insert Data into Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm coding for hours to insert data into my SQL database, but nothing happens.
I even can't debug Java, because I don't get any output of my console.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 *
 * @author xxx
 */
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdata";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";

    private static final DecimalFormat DF2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement stmt;
    private static ResultSet rs;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            try {

                String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                try {
                    Class.forName(myDriver);
                // opening database connection to MySQL server
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);

                // getting Statement object to execute query
                 // the mysql insert statement
                String query = "INSERT INTO customers (customer, currency, amount) values ('Name', 'Currency', 100);";
                stmt.executeUpdate(query);


                // execute the preparedstatement

                // executing SELECT query
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                con.close(); 
                stmt.close();
                rs.close();

            } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
                sqlEx.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

What did I wrong, that nothing happens? Even if I use this code for Java-Classes (not Servlets), I only receive an compile error, but without message.

I'm using the IDE Netbeans and mysql DB is the MySQL Workbench. The Java Class is using the main method.

**Update:**

I've tested following Code with IntelliJ:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdata";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";

        String query = "Insert into customers (customer, currency, amount) values('Michael Ballack', 'Euro', 500)";

        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            pst.executeUpdate();


        } catch (SQLException ex) {

            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(JdbcMySQLVersion.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    private static class JdbcMySQLVersion {

        public JdbcMySQLVersion() {
        }
    }
```

I can insert data into the MySQL database.
In Netbeans this code won't work, although I've implemented the MySQLConnector. I don't know why, but Netbeans seems hard to handle.

Comment: Seems like a lot of exception handling is missing. Does that code even compile?

Comment: You want to use private static Statement stmt, but it never is instanced. You need to do above: PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query); 
preparedStmt.execute();

Comment: What did you mean "Cannot insert Data into Database"? Have you checked the table content in DB and if your servlet has been invoked correctly?

Comment: I checked the table content but nothing was inserted.

Comment: The code as shown will result in a `NullPointerException` because `stmt` is never initialized. Also, things like connections, statements, result sets, etc should not be fields in a servlet, and definitely not static fields, but local variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. If you are using Netbeans with the Glassfish-Server and you want your servlet to save data into the database, you have to make sure that Netbeans has installed the Driver of your Database Connector (e.g. MySQL Connector). But you also have to configurate your server (e.g. Glassfish) which will support the DB Connector drivers.

In my case my Server didn't load the DB Connector Driver so the JDBC Code couldn't be executed.

Here's a useful link to configurate the Glassfish Server: https://dzone.com/articles/nb-class-glassfish-mysql-jdbc

Answer (score 1):

In the servlet code, I don't see you ever write anything to out.  So nothing is being sent back to the browser, even if it compiled.   You could write your SQL exception to the out writer you created.   To be more precise add this in your exception:   out.println(sqlEx.printStackTrace());   That should at least show what exception you are getting back to the browser.

What is the compile error you get outside of a servlet?

This maybe obvious, but to get JDBC stuff to work on your server, you need to have the MySQL server installed, started and configured.  The table referenced has to be defined, etc.   You could check this outside of the Java servlet environment with the tools provided with MySQL.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans and MySQL-Workbench. With NodeJS I can insert any data into the database. I tried to print out the error into the Browser console, but nothing happens.

Comment: I used another IDE for JDBC - IntelliJ. It works with another code. I've found out that NetBeans is not using the MySQLConnector in my project although i've implemented that. :(

Answer (score 0):

1. your code can not compile, you miss catch exception for second 'try'.
2. Where do you use this class to run, if you run a java class, this class must contain main() function?
3. you should use some IDEs like eclipse or IntelliJ to code, it help you detect the error easier.

Comment: Actually I use this class in aber servlet. In my "normal" Java project I use the Main function.

Comment: You can use a try without a catch, this isn't a requirement. Not since the introduction of the try-with-resources, which will automatically close the given resource.

Comment: I've tested the code in IntelliJ. After modifying the code I can finally insert data into the database. The problem is, that I can't use the code in my Netbeans project, although I've implemented the MySQLConnector into Netbeans. :(